# Mongo Java Driver 3.6: Change Streams Codec Error

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I'm trying to use the new ChangeStream feature with Mongo Java Driver 3.6, but I'm stuck. This is my error:

```
ChangeStreamDocument contains generic types that have not been specialised.
Top level classes with generic types are not supported by the PojoCodec.
```

Here's how I'm starting the changeStream:

```
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
        fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));

MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoClientURI.getDatabase())
                                    .withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);

collection.insertOne(Person.builder().age(100).build());
collection.insertOne(Person.builder().age(100).build());
collection.watch().forEach((Block<? super ChangeStreamDocument<Person>>) personChangeStreamDocument -> {
    System.out.println(personChangeStreamDocument.getFullDocument());
});
```

`Person` is just a POJO.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently a bug with the automatic `ProjoCodecProvider` as described in [JAVA-2800](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2800).

The temporary workaround is register the POJO classes manually for example:

```
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                                 fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().register(Person.class).build()));
```

Additionally, please note that you *may* not be able to see the event insert if you performed the insert operation before you open a change stream on a collection. Although you can test this easily by inserting/altering documents from another thread or process. See also [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) for more information.

**UPDATE**: The ticket `JAVA-2800` has been resolved and a fix version is available on MongoDB Java Driver v3.6.4+.